# how do I avoid getting modal is opened multiple times?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to send data to my modal, but however, I am facing an issue where once it opens the modal. it triggers many times as you can see in the image, but however my modal is isn't a `map` function where I loop to gather the information which is sent from another component .

[image: error]

```
return (
    <>
    {data.map((data) => { return (
    <div className="modal__backdrop">
        <div className="modal__container">
            <div className="modal-header">
                <div className="modal-close" onClick={onRequestClose}>
                    <svg className='w-6 h-6' fill='none' viewBox='0 0 24 24' stroke='currentColor'>
                        <path
                            strokeLinecap='round'
                            strokeLinejoin='round'
                            strokeWidth='2'
                            d='M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12'/>
                    </svg>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="job-title-wrapper">
                <div className="job-card-title">{data.tactic_id}</div>
                <div className="job-action">
                    <svg
                        className="heart"
                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                        viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                        fill="none"
                        stroke="currentColor"
                        strokeWidth={2}
                        strokeLinecap="round"
                        strokeLinejoin="round">
                        <path
                            d="M20.8 4.6a5.5 5.5 0 00-7.7 0l-1.1 1-1-1a5.5 5.5 0 00-7.8 7.8l1 1 7.8 7.8 7.8-7.7 1-1.1a5.5 5.5 0 000-7.8z"/>
                    </svg>
                    <svg
                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                        viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                        fill="none"
                        stroke="currentColor"
                        strokeWidth={2}
                        strokeLinecap="round"
                        strokeLinejoin="round"
                        className="feather feather-share-2">
                        <circle cx={18} cy={5} r={3}/>
                        <circle cx={6} cy={12} r={3}/>
                        <circle cx={18} cy={19} r={3}/>
                        <path d="M8.6 13.5l6.8 4M15.4 6.5l-6.8 4"/>
                    </svg>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="job-subtitle-wrapper">
                <div className="company-name">Patreon
                    <span className="comp-location">Londontowne, MD.</span>
                </div>
                <div className="posted">Posted 8 days ago<span className="app-number">98 Application</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="explain-bar">
                <div className="explain-contents">
                    <div className="explain-title">Experience</div>
                    <div className="explain-subtitle">Minimum 1 Year</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="overview-text">
                <div className="overview-text-header">Overview</div>
                <div className="overview-text-subheader">
                    We believe that design (and you) will be critical to the company's success. You
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="overview-text">
                <div className="overview-text-header">Job Description</div>
                <div className="overview-text-item">3+ years working as a product designer.</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>)
    })}
    </>
);
};
```

Comment: That's because you have mapped your modal component using data.

Comment: you might also want to have the model check some state variable on whether it should show itself, and your onRequestClose  either is, or is something which calls a state setter which sets that value to false

Comment: oh, i see, I think I misunderstood the question, your modal isn't being disiplayed multiple times, it's what's whithin it.   As @Dante_97, mentioned.  perhaps it has to do with `data.map((data) =>`
perhaps you should `data.map((item) => ` and make use of item from then on

Comment: First of all, try to come up with easy to read names. data.map((data) ... ) is unnecessary confusing. There is never a good reason to use shadowing.  
Having said that, you know that map returns an array of modified items? And react then renders that array, so I guess you have as many displayed items as there are items in data.